# exchange sd on mashmallow

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, internal-sd

I, probably unwisely, configured a slow sd card in my Marshmallow for storing apps.  Now I want to change it for an ultra or extreme quicker sd card.
How do I prevent the loss of part or all of some apps?
I have an 8 GB Moto E (2nd Gen) with 4G LTE with Android 6.0 patched to 1 Feb2016

Comment: By "configured .. for storing apps", do you mean [adoptable storage](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info)? If so, please follow the link.

Comment: You could temporarily move all apps back to internal storage and then take a backup of data in your SD card to a PC. And then insert a new ultra class Sd card. (As far as I understood the question)

Comment: @AbhishekK if Pete is asking about adoptable storage, he might have to use the corresponding "migrate data" option – provided the device has sufficient internal storage to accept all those data.

Comment: @izzy, I didn't knew that I can actually migrate data back to internal, from the sd card. I thought only reverse was possible.

Comment: @AbhishekK as I wrote, within limits. Actually, your comment and mine must be combined to a 3-step-guide: First, copy all you can to your computer (or any other *external* medium) and verify the copy is fine, second delete all copied stuff from adoptable storage, third use the migrate option to move out the remains. Remember there was a reason you used adoptable storage in the first place (usually lack of internal storage), so it's unlikely *everything* stored there fits back in. // But we're jumping ahead: Pete hasn't yet stated if our guess is correct.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I do not have enough internal storage.   By configured  did mean adoptable storage

Comment: I apologize for the delay in joning in.  I have not used this site before and I understood I would be informed if there were any replies to my query.

Comment: So i will stick around for a while, although Izzy seems to have given me the answer, and I should not worry about apps being half on adoptable and half internal.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand "migrate option".  I can't find it in my phone.  And afterwards don't I need to copy back to the new sd card?  I understood new sd cards were reformatted by Marshmallow when they are adopted.

Comment: I get the feeling you guys are so far advanced you might have problems communicating with someone as ignorant as I am.

Comment: Thanks again, guys, for your kind attention, but I guess you have moved on to pastures new now - so Farewell.